# Sorting words based on how many times they appear in a file

Tags: linux, sorting, unix, cut

In Linux/Unix using puTTy I am trying to interpret a file and return the top 25 most common words in said file. I am currently stuck on removing the field of numbers, leaving just the words in the list, and I am stuck on making all of the upper case into lower case so that when the uniq -c command goes through it counts both variants together.

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' < $1 | sed 's/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/ /g' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rh | head -n 25
```

I have tried multiple ways to cut, including using the "cut" command like so:

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' < $1 | sed 's/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/ /g' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 25 | cut -d " " -f 2
```

Which uses a roundabout way to cut through the deliminator of a space, which is what the file outputs as a list (`345 the`, `223 of`, etc.) When the `tr` for upper->lower goes through it makes everything lowercase but I am still getting the two types separated. On one I have to do for the frankenstein book the word "the" appears twice because one is the capitalized version and the other is the non-capitalized version, and although they look identical on the output, it isnt functioning correctly.

Edit: The removing the count is no longer a problem, thank you @pmacfarlane for that solution. I still have a problem with either the upper to lower tr command, or the sed command. The sed command isn't removing apostraphies or quotation marks. The list is also separating instances of the word "the". After extending past 25 I saw that there were three separate but seemingly identical instances of the word "the". Which means while the tr is doing its job in lowering the case, it seems that in addition to it not combining the lower and upper case into one unique variable, it is also making more instances on factors I am not aware of.

Comment: Pipe to `grep -v '^[0-9]+$'` to remove lines that are all numbers.

Comment: Changing `cut -d " " -f 2` (in your second example) to `awk '{print $2}'` fixes one of your problems.

Comment: Regex is almost always the wrong tool.

Comment: Please post a representative input file. We want to know if you have valid contractions like `can't` and/or quoted strings such as: `The secret word is: 'hello'` so we know how to remove punctuation. Also, rather than your long regex (e.g. `.,\/#`) how about: `-e s/[^a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*/ /g -e s/ /\n/g` Also, almost of all of the pipeline can be [easily] replaced with `perl`

Comment: *"the word "the" appears twice because one is the capitalized version ..."* . What do you get if you type `file YourFrankenstienText.txt` ? Is that data sourced from a European country? Maybe `LANG=c tr -s ...` will help. Good luck.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for better complete answers.